# Is it possible to display the control center in button click? ios

Tags: ios, control-center

I'm having a problem in displaying the control center in iOS, i've been searching for some docs regarding on this issue but couldn't find an answer.
Is there a way, to make the control center appear by clicking a UIButton?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply constraints programatically to a specific UI element ([link to iOS developer doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html))

Sample code of this eg.:

```
// Center horizontally
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewToBeCentered
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

// Center vertically
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewToBeCentered
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

You can include this code into your button's action code.

Hope this helps to achieve the desired effect!

Comment: What he asked? and what you answered?

Comment: @Anil I asked how to display the control center by click a uibutton

Comment: Sorry.. i miss understood your question @AldrinEquila

Comment: It's ok @anil. No problem